New Fields from Dependency Extension Not Visible in Business Central
In Business Central, I am experiencing an issue. For example:
In Extension A, I added a new field and published it to the server. However, when I reference Extension A as a dependency in Extension B, I cannot see the new fields from Extension A.
I’m not sure if this is related to caching or something else. Could someone help me?

Please elaborate with some code examples e.g., how have you configured resourceExposurePolicy in app.json, the table and field definition from Extension A, the dependency reference in Extension B etc.
